# Freeform v3 file upload fails to send file to server

Tags: solspace-freeform

Freeform properly displays a form containing text fields, hidden fields and a "file1" file type field and using enctype="multipart/form-data". However, when the form submits, it only sends the other form fields using application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

I suspect there is some sort of javascript involved. How do I get Freeform to process the file upload portion of the form?

```
        {exp:freeform:form
            required="name|phone|email|message"
            collection="Job Applications"                                                                     
            form:class="form-style"
            file_upload="Documents"                                                                           
            allowed_file_types="doc|docx|pdf"                                                                 
            notify="{careers_email}"                                                                          
            form:enctype="multipart/form-data"                                                                
            return="notifications/application-confirmation"}                                                  

<snip />                                                                                                              
                    <li>                                                                                      
                        <label for="input_file1">Upload Resume (pdf or MS Word .doc(x) format)</label>        
                        <input type="file" name="file1" id="input_file1" />                                   
                    </li>                                                                                     
<snip />                                                                             

        {/exp:freeform:form}
```

version: Freeform v3.1.0

Comment: Can you please share a snippet of your template containing the Freeform tags?